# What does "T" represent in this code?

Tags: java

```
T get(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return a[i];
}
T set(int i, T x) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    T y = a[i];
    a[i] = x;
    return y;
}
```

I'm looking over some coding examples from my textbook, but they never mention what T is. I'm not sure how to search about this since I don't know what it's called or it's purpose.
I was wondering if someone can show me a write-up or some info about this. Thank you

Comment: It's a generic type parameter -- think of it as "some type, T." See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Can we see a complete class definition.  I'd hope T is a generic type, and not the name of a class...

Comment: You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Answer (score 1):

`T` represents an object type using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Whatever type `x` is in the `set` call, the `set` method will return that same type. In the `get` call, the return type is `T`, too. That type must be defined somewhere else, probably in the type of the class, where it might show up as `<T>`.

So if this is a class that is some sort of collections (since it is dealing with indexes), it might be defined as:

```
public class SomeCollection<T> {
```

Then it might get instantiated like:

```
SomeCollection<String> arr = new SomeCollection<String>();
```

In that case, `T` would be `String`, and the return type of the `get` and `set` methods, and the type of `set` parameter `x`, would all be `String`.

If it gets instantiated like:

```
SomeCollection<Integer> arr = new SomeCollection<Integer>();
```

then `T` is an `Integer`.

You could have both in the same code, without having to write two (or more) different versions of `SomeCollection`.